# OPC UA Historical Data Access - Event History

Tags: opc, opc-ua

I would like to know if there is some currently available OPC UA Client supporting Historical Data Access, more precisely for Data AND Event History.

UA Expert from Unified Automation seems like to be one of the most advanced OPC UA Client, but it only supports historizing Data not Event.

I wonder if there is a better OPC UA Client that will do both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SampleConsoleClient that comes as a sample with the [Prosys OPC UA Java SDK](http://www.prosysopc.com/opc-ua-java-sdk.php) (free evaluation version available) to read the data history of a variable (with HistoryRead in AccessLevel) and event history of an object node (with HistoryRead in EventNotifier).

The sample application comes with source so you can also modify the client to your needs.

<strike>[Prosys OPC UA Java Client](http://www.prosysopc.com/opc-ua-java-client.php) does not provide event history quite yet.</strike>

UPDATE: [Prosys OPC UA Client](http://www.prosysopc.com/products/opc-ua-client/) provides an Event History view, too.

Comment: Thanks Jouni, that was I was looking for ! I already tried Prosys OPC UA Java Client and History Data works well, now I will try your Java SDK for History Event

Comment: Read History Event works well ! Now I'm waiting for it in your JAVA OPC UA Client !

Comment: This feature is in the Prosys OPC UA Client nowadays (renamed from OPC UA Java Client).

Answer (score 1):

Actually UA Expert does show historical events. From the top menu go to Document -> Add -> Event View. And then drag and drop the Server node (for all events on the server) or any other node (for subset of events) from the Address space explorer into the configuration window of the event view. Then in the event history tab you'll be able to specify start and end date and retrieve the events.

Comment: Thanks. Yes they implemented it nowadays. That wasn't the case 6years ago AFAICR

Answer (score 0):

Use Kepware KepServer EX V5  Simulation for the getting the live data on to  the Client.

Just create the group and add the items.

If you are good in programming , connect it to OPC Server and get the live tag data

Comment: The last version of KEPServerEX (5.13) still does not provide OPC UA Historical Data Access from its OPC UA Driver Client, neither Data nor Events History....